# One button for multiple text boxes

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.6

Is it possible to have 1 calculate button for 3 text boxes or do I need a button for each text box, the text boxes are, Barrels, Gallons and Liters, if I put 10 in Barrel box I want the button to calculate how many Gallons and Liters 10 Barrels are.  And same if I put 10 in Liters box I want the button to calculate how many Barrels and Gallons that is.
This is the code I have now:

```
- (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender {
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

float a = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:_Barrels.text] floatValue];
float b = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:_Gallons.text] floatValue];
float c = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:_Liters.text] floatValue];


_Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a];
_Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a * 42];
_Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a * 159];

_Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b * .0238];
_Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b];
_Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b * 3.785];

_Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c * .0063];
_Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c * .264];
_Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c];

switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 1:
        [_Barrels resignFirstResponder];
        [_Gallons resignFirstResponder];
        [_Liters resignFirstResponder];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have one button to do all three.  The only hard part would be keeping track of which bos the user entered the value in.

Comment: Ok thank you Dan, is it possible that you could help me out with that.

Comment: You need to devise some scheme, such as flagging the last text box that had text entered, using `UITextFieldDelegate`, or doing something like any time a user begins editing one text box, you clear the all of them, and then when the user presses the button, only the last edited text box will have text in it, so you can assume thats the base one for calculation

Comment: I am pretty new in this programming, is it possible that you could help me out with some codes just to get me going.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) and see if you can think of a way to implement the methods I suggested with what is outlined there

Comment: I am just totally lost here now :(

Comment: Perhaps post another question specifically about what the problem you are having is, and I will see if I can help you along the way

Comment: Same problem as before Dan :/ Don't know what method to use doing this